# null pointer exception in lookup for weblogic mail session

Tags: email, session, weblogic, lookup

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'mail.IHCMailSession' didn't find subcontext 'mail'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'mail/IHCMailSession'

I have defined jndi as mail/IHCMailSession and searching as

```
    InitialContext ic;
    try {
        ic = new InitialContext();
        session = (Session)ic.lookup(mail/IHCMailSession);
```

Please help me how to fix this

Comment: Usually the first thing to check is that you correctly picked a Target server when creating the mail session in the WebLogic configuration.

Comment: i choose the admin server and application deployed on it.

Comment: Are they any errors in the startup logs? If the resource isn't being initialized on startup, you will see this error.